# Can you hack a hashed password when the salt is stored next to the hash?

Tags: passwords, hash, salt

Ok, so I've been reading (a lot!) about security and the whole deal about hashing, salting, encrypting, etc. and something I keep seeing is really bugging me.  It seems a lot of people that really seem to know their stuff keeps saying it's OK to store the salt with the hashed password in the DB.

I can't help but to wonder, why?  What if your DB is dumped?  They have access to everything which, to me, means they can look at any one record and voila(!) there's the hashed password and the plain text salt right next to it.  That gives them the info they need to run it against rainbow tables and/or dictionary attacks doesn't it?

I must be missing something (yeah, that's never happened before!!) and would really enjoy some enlightenment on the matter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rainbow tables are ineffective against a collection of differently-salted passwords, even if the salt is known; you would have to build a different table for each salt, and that defeats the entire purpose of rainbow tables.  It will be faster for an attacker to brute-force each password individually.  This is the purpose of having per-user salt.

In other words, rainbow tables are only effective when you are trying to break many passwords that were all digested the same way, using the same digest algorithm.  Throwing in different salt for each password means that the passwords are *not* all digested the same way.

Comment: Ahh, I see!  But what about the brute-forcing?  I mean why leave the salt right there for them to use?  Again, I know I must be missing something.

Comment: Given a password of sufficient length, brute-forcing passwords may take many years.  The purpose of adding the salt is to prevent an attacker from being able to take your database of 100,000 users and discover the passwords for 1,000 of those users in a matter of minutes, or even seconds.  The same database but with per-user salts would likely take the attacker years to crack the *first* password.  It's unlikely that an attacker will spend that amount of time to obtain one password.  Salting each password differently basically prevents the attacker from efficiently re-using work.

Comment: Note that some systems use a single, site-wide salt.  If an attacker is able to obtain that salt then he can build a rainbow table specific to that salt and then efficiently attempt to attack your list of passwords.  That's why random, *per-user* salt is recommended.  It's not about *preventing* the discovery of your user's credentials (*nothing* can do that if all of your data is compromised), but rather to make it so incredibly time-consuming for the attacker that he doesn't even try.  (Or, if he's dumb enough to try, wastes a ton of time producing no results.)

Comment: Now that makes sense.  So it sounds like its meant more as a deterrent against an attack against the whole of the db forcing the hacker to focus on individual accounts, right? EDIT: You already answered, thanks so much!!

Comment: Basically, yes.  Some sites go so far as to implement multiple-round digests.  If you make, say, 100 passes of the digest function (feeding the output back into the function) then you don't really increase site load very much, because authentication is likely not going to be your site's bottleneck.  (Usually disk I/O or memory are.)  But this will cause a brute-force attack to take *100 times as long*.  There are even some digest algorithms designed specifically to be very CPU and memory intensive for this very reason.

Comment: The obvious becomes obvious when explained so well. Thanks.
I always thought having the salt in the database would be pointless too, but come to think of it, it does help.
I am assuming then, 1 constant salt + 1 random stored salt + pass all hashed together using a good hash function is invincible?(In the end developers just want to know what is best)

Comment: @DamienGolding Nothing is invincible in the security world, but this would indeed be adequate protection against rainbow-table attacks.  (The "constant salt" isn't necessary or even beneficial; random per-entry salt is sufficient.)

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks. What do you mean by not beneficial? The reason for the constant salt would be that it is not accessible from the database meaning that it would also have to be breached or cracked. Does it really have no effect?

Comment: @DamienGolding In that sense it is beneficial, but per-entry salt already prevents rainbow table attacks and without those it will (depending on password strength) take years to brute-force just one password.